# HtmlAgilityPack saving webpage issue

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm having a problem with saving html pages using HAP. For most websites I can use these codes but this one: http://techstacks.io/tech/C. I just can get the html of the main page http://techstacks.io saved only, no matter what sub-directories I use in my code:

```
HtmlWeb htmlweb = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = htmlweb.Load("http://techstacks.io/tech/C");
document.Save(@"C:\Users\ADM\Desktop\Oisix\new.html");
```

Please help! My thanks in advance!

Comment: Wha's the error message you're getting? Also, are you using HAP just to save pages? if that's the case then why not use a `WebClient` instead?

Comment: I get no errors, it just give me the html of the homepage: techstack.io only. I used WebClient and got the same result.

Comment: It's because the page rendering relies on JavaScript. You must be able to process javascript for the page to render correctly. For that you can use a WebBrowser control or something like CEFSharp then save the rendered HTML.

Comment: Thanks man, you're the best :)

Comment: An alternative to `CEFSharp` widely used is [nuget's package Selenium Web Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver)